# Setting Custom hiddenDays in Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

We can hide particular days of week from fullcalendar by Setting **hiddenDays** property.

i need to hide alternate saturdays of a month.

is it possible in any way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`dayRender`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/dayRender/) callback function:

> This callback lets you modify day cells that are part of the month,
>   basicWeek, and basicDay views. See Available Views.
>
> date is the native Date object for the given day.

to check if the displayed is an odd saturday; to do so you can get the number of week of the date and check if it's odd.

Code:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth = function(exact) {
    var month = this.getMonth()
        , year = this.getFullYear()
        , firstWeekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()
        , lastDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
        , offsetDate = this.getDate() + firstWeekday - 1
        , index = 1 // start index at 0 or 1, your choice
        , weeksInMonth = index + Math.ceil((lastDateOfMonth + firstWeekday - 7) / 7)
        , week = index + Math.floor(offsetDate / 7)
    ;
    if (exact || week < 2 + index) return week;
    return week === weeksInMonth ? index + 5 : week;
};

function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;}

$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [{
        title: 'event1',
        start: '2014-01-07'
    }, {
        title: 'event2',
        start: '2014-01-10',
        end: '2013-05-15'
    }, {
        title: 'event3',
        start: '2014-01-13 12:30:00',
        allDay: false // will make the time show
    }],
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        if (date.getDay() == 6 && isOdd(date.getWeekOfMonth())) {
            $(cell).addClass('fc-disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/cjTF9/