# Fullcalendar.js disabling custom days from agendaWeek (custom hiddenDays)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js plugin and I believe it is great and fills my needs, except one feature that I need. This feature is to disable (better - hide, not display at all) arbitrary (custom) days from (at least) agendaWeek view. Now, I can only disable specific weekDays with hiddenDays option.

During research about it, I have only found this topic:
[Setting Custom hiddenDays in Full Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479552/setting-custom-hiddendays-in-full-calendar)

Which does not help me (it does not work, only disables (not "deletes, hides") days in month view.

Similar feature has been requested, but no response. https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3130

So my question is, is there any way to achieve this? Either by hacking the JS code, or somehow modifying CSS with display: none? If so, which parts of the code I should look at and how, that could be modified to achieve my goal?

If anyone would have any idea I would be very grateful. Also I believe this feature could be useful for more people.

Thank you.